# Get input element positioned correctly

Tags: html, css, input, position

The `input` element is not going fully inside parent. I want `input` to be at center of the parent but its getting some margin from top. What css is to be added for fixing it?

```css
#menu
{
 height:30px;
 background: #ccc;
}

#board-name
{
 display:block;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 height: 80%;
        vertical-align: middle;
 min-width:200px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
 <span id="plus">+</span>
 <input id="board-name" value=''/>
</div>
```

Comment: Float or absolutely position the plus icon element ...

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjVXbM what are you doing with the `+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use:

```
#board-name {
    margin-top: -18px;
}
```

Or call

```
#plus {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I want to make it centered vertically also. Any way?

Answer (score 0):

use position:relative to your parent and a position:absolute to your child. then try margin: auto or you can just mess with left:XX and right:XX

Answer (score 0):

Center the input and float the +:

```css
#menu
{
  height:30px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
#plus
{
  float:left;
}
#board-name
{
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height: 80%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width:200px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
 <span id="plus">+</span>
 <input id="board-name" value=''/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make little changes to your css like below and it also contains your code and little bit another

```
     #menu
     {
     height:30px;
     background: #ccc;
     }
     #plus {
     float: left;
     }
     #board-name
     {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 80%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     min-width:200px;
     position: relative;    
     top: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     }
```